# Kotlin, calculating percentage of BigDecimal values, having issues with multiply / divide

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to calculate the percentage of BigDecimal values. But I am receiving "None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: " error

```
  val data = myData
                 .groupBy { 
                    it.category to it.tags["prod"] 
                  }
                  .map { (key, value) ->
                        listOf(
                            key.first,
                            key.second,
                            value.sumOf { it.cost.toBigDecimal() }
                        )
                   }


                data.forEach { totalCostData ->
                    totalCost = totalCost.add(totalCostData[2] as BigDecimal)
                }

                data.forEach { costData ->
                    val percentage =  costData[2].BigDecimal().multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(100)) / totalCost

                    addPercentageData(costData[0].toString(), percentage)
                }
         }
```

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Comment: `.BigDecimal()` - what is this code supposed to do? Do you really have a member function called `BigDecimal`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kotlin documentation [says](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/typecasts.html#unsafe-cast-operator):

> The unsafe cast in Kotlin is done by the infix operator as:
>
> ````kotlin
> val x: String = y as String```
> ````

So your syntax that uses `.BigDecimal()` won't work as expected, and as far as I got from the code, `costData[2]` is already `BigDecimal`, so you don't need to cast anything there, just try to rewrite your percentage calc like this:

```kotlin
data.forEach { costData ->
    val percentage = costData[2]
        .multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(100))
        .divide(totalCost, 2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)

    addPercentageData(costData[0].toString(), percentage)
}
```